# How to curve an array correctly

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am having huge issues curbing an object.  I have a tube that has been made out of an array of objects to create a ribbed effect.  But when I go to curve it using a bezier curve the it distorts some of the shape massively and other parts not at all, even on relatively "flat" sections of he curve.  All of the tube should look like the section at the end on he image.  Of course I expect some distortion but this is bizarre.

Any help would be really appreciated.  I am a real novice on Blender and I cant find any videos that deal with this issue (maybe I don't know how what to search for to get the right result though).

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Make sure both the curve and the object share the same origin point.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have made sure they have the same origin point.  Thanks though Christopher.

Comment: I think I have have shared it correctly moonboots, I didn't know you could do that, thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't worry, I think Ive got it.  I didnt realise that you needed to have the object you were curving directly over the Bezier curve for it to deform less. *Facepalm*.

Comment: @NCO If you found a solution can you please write it as an answer? Other users with the same issue will appreciate your help.